# not less than php !<

Tags: php, for-loop, operators

I have looked on here and many have said there is no way to have an operator !<, because if something is !< then it must be =.. But I am trying to define conditions to not include results from a foreach loop.

for the sake of this example the results from the foreach returns 25 results and each $results holds a value incremented by 10

```
for ($block = 10; $block <= 250; $block+=10 ) {
    echo $block . '<br>';
}
```

This would be the result

```
 $a = 10
 $b = 20
 $c = 30
 $d = 40
 $e = 50 
 $f = 60
 $g = 70
 $h = 80
 $i = 90
 $j = 100
 ... and so no
```

Within the foreach loop

```
 $dropBefore =30; 
 $dropAfter =90; 

 if ($block >= $dropBefore && $block <= $dropAfter - 1){
```

---

Results are

```
 $c = 30
 $d = 40
 $e = 50 
 $f = 60
 $g = 70
 $h = 80
 $i = 90
```

My problem now, I want to target $d, $e, $f to remove and leave remaining results
Where my results look like

```
 $c = 30
 $g = 70
 $h = 80
 $i = 90

I have 2 variables 
$start_value = 40
$finish_value = 60

if($block != $startValue && !<$finishValue){ 
    //$block != $startValue removes $d, 
    but !<$finishValue is invalid and I get the syntax error unexpected !
```

If I say

```
if($block != $startValue && < $finishValue){ 
    //$block != $startValue removes $d, 
    but < $finishValue  removes everything greater than $f and $e and $f remains
$e = 50
$f = 60
```

How do I say keep everything but remove $startValue, $finishValue, and anything in between them?

Comment: yes I have, >= removes everything less than the $finishValue including the $c that I want to keep

Comment: Try `<?` and `?>`. Those are the operators I always see being used in PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests that a whole slew of separate variables gets created, but that does not happen with the code you've provided. Your question with respect to manipulating results derived from iteration is interesting and certainly a fair one.  The below code meets the restrictions and exclusions you've specified.  If you wish to also store the resulting values that get displayed, then using an array would keep things nicely organized, as follows:

```
<?php

$start_value = 40;
$finish_value = 60;

$dropBefore = 30; 
$dropAfter = 90;
$let = 'a';
$arr = null;

for ($block = 10; $block <= 250; $block+=10 ) {
    if (( $block >= $dropBefore ) && ( $block <= $dropAfter ) ) {
        if ( $block >= $start_value && $block <= $finish_value ) {
            continue;
        }
        echo $block,"\n";
        $arr[$let++] = $block;
    }
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Any values between 40 and 60 will simply be ignored as the loop continues at the top again instead of executing the 'echo $block,"\n"' statement.  I also found that I had to eliminate the '-1' with respect to '<= $dropAfter -1' since it prevented '90' from appearing in the result. I made the keys of the array alphabetical in case you prefer such keys.

Output:

```
30
70
80
90
array(4) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(30)
  ["b"]=>
  int(70)
  ["c"]=>
  int(80)
  ["d"]=>
  int(90)
}
```

Comment: for what I wanted yes I needed the -1... but what you generated with the code was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the late response but even though it worked I wanted to keep going over it until I understood it completely. genius.... absolute genius Thank you

Comment: I do have a question for you?

Comment: The $startValue and $finishValue output is from a loop as well. Basically I am trying to output available time $blocks based on appointments made.. When echo $block the last value from the loop is present but the other values are not. so if user1 start and finish value is 9am-10am, that is blocked out. but user2 selects time from 12p-1p. User2 times is blocked and user1 time reappears

Comment: @tru it sounds like you're working on an appointment booking app which will require working with PHP and a database such as MySQL. You may find this link instructive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979992/best-practice-for-php-mysql-appointment-booking-system. And this one details the steps you need to follow: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/create-online-booking-system-13724.html. But you may not need to reinvent the wheel; see this: https://code.google.com/p/phpmyreservation/wiki/Download?tm=2

Answer (score 1):

Something !< is, in fact, >=, not =.

But you want values < than $startValue OR > than $finishValue to show, so:

```
if($block < $startValue || $block > $finishValue) echo $block
```

Not sure why you changed your logic. You used pretty much the same a few lines above.

Comment: this is right.  if its not less than it must be greater than or equal to

Comment: I thought < || > as well but that gives me either or with the > $finishValue being the last condition and the return results are everything > $finishValue and nothing below $finishValue, so the $c was removed as well.

Comment: It shouldn't, because 30<40||30>60 is true||false which is true. Try again with the comparison I put there. Maybe you used a different comparison when you tried it?

Comment: actually yes I did something wrong... i wrote the code completely over and it worked..but I do have a dilemma now that it is working. The $startValue and $finishValue output is from a loop as well. Basically I am trying to output available time $blocks based on appointments made..the     if($block < $startValue || $block > $finishValue).. When echo $block the last value from the loop is present but the other values are not. so if user1 start and finish value is 9am-10am, that is blocked out. but user2 selects time from 12p-1p. User2 times is blocked and user1 time reappears